# Load activities on ViewPagers

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to load my activities on a viewpager. Before i add the pageviewer i had a button and it sent me to an activity. Into that activity i was doing many sort of things like loading from database and calculating some values. Now i added a ViewPager, so when i press  the button it opens a pager xml and on each tab i load the xml of my activity i want to load. But i dont know how can i also load the actual activity into the Viewpager. 
Now the ViewPager just shows my activity xml's but they do nothing, and no values are loaded into them.
here is some of my code:

```
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fuel_pager);

        MyFragmentFuel mFragmentFuel = new MyFragmentFuel();
        MyFragmentDetails mFragmentDetails = new MyFragmentDetails();
        MyFragmentGraphs mFragmentGraphs = new MyFragmentGraphs();

        mPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPagerAdapter.addFragment(mFragmentFuel);
        mPagerAdapter.addFragment(mFragmentDetails);
       // mPagerAdapter.addFragment(mFragmentGraphs);

        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
}


public class MyFragmentDetails extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_fuel_details, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot load an activity in a viewpager (actually, you can, but that's really complicated for little gain)

Comment: Load Fragments not Activities.